# How to reset a ViewController after pressing the homebutton and get back to the same ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an Application which has some animations going on. If the user presses the homebotton and decides to get back into the application - to the ViewController, where the animations takes place - the ViewController should be displayed as the user just entered it reguarily (Animations start from the beginning). I am using `CABasigAnimation`. Can someone please tell me how to reset the ViewController or something similar?

I was thinking about the Lifecycle of the ViewController, but I was not able to find a method similar to Android Activity's `onRestart()` method, where you can put some code if the userer enters the Activity **again**.

Code for the animation:

```
CAShapeLayer *progressCircle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
//....
[self.view.layer addSublayer:progressCircle];
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
//....
[progressCircle addAnimation:drawAnimation2 forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method you are looking for is in your AppDelegate class. All opening/closing and system notifications take place in AppDelegate.m

The method you are looking for in AppDelegate.m is:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

In order to receive this notification on your desired viewController you must add the following to your controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(resetAnimationMethod)
                                         name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

Then you simply create a method `-resetAnimationMethod` and insert the code there to restore the default animation.

To remove old layers:

```
for (CALayer *oldLayers in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
    [oldLayers removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I implemented the resetAnimationMethod and I managed to start the animation again. But the prior animation is still visible and I cant figure out, how to delete it. I added the code for my animation in the question

Comment: @moobi you must remove the old layer you added (progressCircle) before resetting your animation. To do so you must add the following right before your animation code: self.view.layer = nil;

Comment: If I like to use `self.view.layer = nil;` an error occurs saying: "Assignment to readonly property" :(

Comment: @moobi then you must loop through the layers and remove them. see edit I made within the answer

Comment: Now the following error occurs during runtime: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x17005c680> was mutated while being enumerated.'
Why cant I change oldLayers in a loop???

Comment: Ok I got the solution now, based on your answer. I found a similar codesnippet to delete old Layers `[self.view.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];`. After this line of code I restarted the animation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try reseting it on   viewWillAppear() 
or similar such methods which get called for various phases while transitioning from one viewController to other .

Answer (score 0):

You could nullify the data source used to populate the table view, then use reload data on the table view itself. As you just nullified the data source and reloaded the table view it will now be empty. Just nullify and reload on the view lifecycle viewWillDisappear for example.

Then, when your user goes back to the table view, you simply populate the data source, reload the table view and do your animations.